# Course recommendation if I Iiked Analysis and Topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, soft-question

If I have studied Real Analysis, Analysis (with metric spaces) and Topology courses and I really  them all,

What would be other courses  that I would also really like ? Based on this 3 courses already taken.

In other words

Which theories or courses has the same essence as Real Analysis, Analysis (with metric spaces) and Topology ?

In other words

Is there a mixed field that includes Analysis and topology?

For example what about the variants of Topology? Which are Algebraic Topology, Differential Topology, Geometric Topology.

Will I like them?

Will I like Functional Analysis, Measure Theory, Approximation Theory, *other* theory, *other* Analysis ?

Could you please guide ?

Comment: How are we to know what you will like? Analysis is a broad area, and it might happen that you like (or dislike) certain parts of it, but that's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Well maybe Algebraic Topology it's very similar to Topology, hence there are high probabilities that I would like Algebraic Topology too. Or maybe Algebraic Topology has almost nothing to do with the theory that you learn in Topology, hence there would be low probability that I would like

Comment: Far from having almost nothing to do with the theory that you see in Topology, Algebraic Topology uses practically every technique that you learn in ordinary topology, together with a ton of techniques from abstract algebra (hence the name "algebraic topology"). However, as suggested by @MisterRiemann, this does not make it any less impossible to predict whether *you* will like algebraic topology.

Comment: Maybe a less subjective question would give you more useful answers.

Comment: Well now I know for sure that I wouldn't like Algebraic topology, because includes Abstract Algebra

Comment: Perhaps I should have asked, Which theories or courses has the same essence as Real Analysis, Analysis (with metric spaces) and Topology ?

Comment: My guess is functional analysis, but I'm curious why you don't just look at books in a library, course notes posted on the internet, etc. to see what's involved with these fields? Or are you seeking the opinions of other people in order to supplement what you've already learned by doing this?

Comment: You may also like [differential geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry), [symplectic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_geometry), [dynamical systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system), and applications to [hamiltonian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics).

Comment: Have you studied complex analysis?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro sure I can do that. To search about this 6 fields. But what I miss a field? What if there is a mix between Analysis and topology that I don't know about, hence I need to ask here, I thought it would be helpful.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley yes

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro notice how Jean recommended courses that I've never heard before

Comment: Regarding courses taken that you've never heard of, it might be helpful to give some more details about your circumstances, because when I was in college/university there was a course catalog that listed all courses offered by the math department (and for each of the several dozen other departments of the university), and if anything, the actual courses that got offered over a 3 or 4 year period for most every college/university was nearly always a proper subset of those listed in the catalog.

Comment: For example, here are the listings of [undergraduate courses](https://lsa.umich.edu/math/undergraduates/undergraduate-math-courses.html) and [graduate courses](https://lsa.umich.edu/math/graduates/graduate-courses-by-area.html) for The University of Michigan.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Out of curiosity, what do "100-level", "200-level"... mean? Does it correspond to a year?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: This can vary with the university, but typically (and in the case of University of Michigan), 100-level means a course roughly designed for a first year student (18-19 years old; examples include college algebra, precalculus, calculus I & II, introduction to philosophy, chemistry I & II, etc.) and 200-level means a course roughly designed for a second year student (e.g. calculus III, differential equations, genetics, organic chemistry, etc.), and so on. Generally, 300-level and 400-level are not differentiated all that much and are often collectively called **(continued)**

Comment: "upper level courses". 500-level courses are generally transition undergraduate-graduate level courses, being courses a good undergraduate planning to attend graduate school could take, as well as courses that a less well prepared graduate student to a beginning graduate student (especially in a terminal Masters degree program) could take for graduate credit. See also the discussion in the Academia Stack Exchange question [How does the college course 101 numbering system work?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/108768)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks a lot! Very interesting to compare to french academia.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro It does not need to be a 'formal' university course, I am going to study by myself, self-learning